# No route matches [POST] "/tv_series/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I display the form, I type in some stuff then I want it to take to the index view

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @series, :url => { :action => :new } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Series Title" %>
  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :actor %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Can some one please help me indentify the error for me? I don't know why its not creating the tvseries when I try to create, when I check `tvseries.connection`, it says its `nil`, there isn't anything in.

**tv_series_controller.rb**

```
 class TvSeriesController < ApplicationController
   def index
   end

   def new
     @series = Series.new
   end

   def create
     @series = Series.new(serie_params)
     if @series.save
       redirect_to root_path
     else
       render 'new'
     end
   end

   private
     def show
       params.require(:series).permit(:title, :description,:actor)
     end
 end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h1>New Serie</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tv_series
  root 'tv_series#index'
end
```

**_create_series.rb**

```
class CreateSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :series do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :actor
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `, :url => { :action => :new }` and you should be good to go.

This is because there is no route that matches `POST /tv_series/new`. Instead let Rails figure out the route for you by removing the line above and it will use `POST /tv_series`.

If you run `rake routes` you should be able to see all of the available routes along w/ their corresponding HTTP verb (GET, POST, PATCH, etc)

*On a sidenote I think your private method is named incorrectly. Looks like you have `def show` when what you meant to have is `def serie_params`.*

Answer (score 0):

Run **rake routes** to the console you will get different path for HTTP Verb (GET, POST, PUT/PATCH, DELETE)

Accordingly use the path.

In your case for creating tv_series you have to use post HTTP verb.
Replace :url => { :action => :new } with create action path provided for POST HTTP verb. It will work fine.

Refer this link: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: This approach will work for creating a record however the OP will run into problems when using this same partial for edit/update as the URL is hardcoded.

Comment: Yes but you can make use ternary operator to handle this situation. by using new_record? method. Refer this link http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/new_record%3F

Comment: Thanks very much i did figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

For rails 4, as default it has same name of controller, model, and view. In this context, you have different name of model and controller/view. So you have to determine your URL in your form into this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @series, :url => { :controller => :tv_series, :action => :create }, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= simple_form_for @series, :url => tv_series_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
```

I hope this help you.